# PHP: Avoid Adding break lines automatically for multiline strings when writing files

Tags: php, html

I have a System which makes a new .html file after Inserting some Article information. But, there is a **Textarea** to input some HTML format codes.Of course there are lot of new lines in that String.I need To write that HTML code to **.html** file.
My Code Is This

```
$my_file = 'index.html';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = '<h6>
          Hello!,World
        </h6>';
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

***actually i get `$data` from a `TEXTAREA`. Hope There Is No big difference there***

I need **FILE CONTENTS** be Like This In my `.html` File

```
<h6>Hello!,World</h6>
```

But I get something like this

```
<h6>\r\n  Hello!,World\r\n</h6>
```

Can Someone Explain How I can stop PHP's Auto add Breaklines system

EDIT: Fine,Didn't Got the exact answer yet! But,Hoped To say this. When We Write a html code there are lot of line breaks,spaces,etc...Like this.

```
 <div class="post-content">
      <h6>
         Hello!,Yellow
      </h6>
      <!-- Post Tags -->
 </div>
```

So when This Like code is Input Into A Text Area And Being written To A file It Do Not needed To Be like

```
<div class="post-content">\r\n<h6>\r\n  Hello!,Yellow\r\n</h6>\r\n<!-- Post Tags -->\r\n</div>
```

RIGHT! I don't Know whether it's a error in my code, But I just need to know whether there is a method to stop file to be like that. 
ALSO, when that TEXTAREA content is Inserted into a MySQL Database It Looks Perfectly Fine Like this

```
<div class="post-content">
      <h6>
         Hello!,Yellow
      </h6>
      <!-- Post Tags -->
 </div>
```

Comment: Consider using a wsyiwyg editor like e.g. TinyMCE instead of just a textarea if you want to write markup in it.

Comment: what you get is exactly what you wrote. what you possibly want is `$data='<h6>'.'Hello!,World'.'</h6>';` (break after each dot)

Comment: alternatively you can split on linebreaks and join again

Comment: "actually i get $data from a TEXTAREA. Hope There Is No big difference there" - there *IS* a big difference: Text Areas can contain line breaks as the ones you are getting.

Comment: I think str_replace also work in this case.

Comment: I am trying to write to the file what i get from a `TEXTAREA` exactly(**with same spacing,line breaks,complete identically**). Is There a WAY

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "Auto add Breaklines system," what you are seeing with `\r\n` is a visual representation of a carriage return and a new line in the passed string.

You can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the `\r\n` with `''`. Or, you can use a fancy [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace both `\s+` and `\r\n` with `''`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace()`this way to replace all these newline commands in your `$data` variable with simple spaces:

```
$to_be_replaced = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replacement = array(" ", " ", " ");

$data_changed = str_replace($to_be_replaced, $replacement, $data);
```

Addition after comments:

If you rather want to *keep* the line breaks and spaces as written into the text area field, you could replace the newline commands with `<br>`tags to keep the line breaks.

With spaces it's more problematic, since HTML will merge all multiple spaces into one space. But you could try to replace " " (i.e. a space) with " " (i.e. a non-breaking space HTML entity, which will also be accepted multiple times after each other.

So the code for that that would be

```
$to_be_replaced = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r", " ");
$replacement = array("<br>", "<br>", "<br>", "&nbsp;");
$data_changed = str_replace($to_be_replaced, $replacement, $data);
```

If you don't use a monospace font, this won't look exactly the same as in the textarea (because characters of different fonts will have different widths), but it should come close.

Comment: But why does this thing just happens when writing it in a file? And according to this `str_replace()` method I have to run a PHP code to replace all those newline commands inside the `.html` file. There should be another way.What I need Is i need to write that string into file without `\r\n`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean - you *do*  have PHP code up there in your question. Whereever you process the content for your HTML output, just insert those three lines after fetching the textarea contents

Comment: Yes Thats what I need to DO. But After writing into file File Contents are like `<h6>\r\n  Hello!,World\r\n</h6>` It's not good.Am I doing something wrong in here or Is there a way to stop it?

Comment: Ahh, I just saw your most recent comment under your question. In this case (i.e. keep linebreaks and spaces), you can use `<br>` as replacement for the newline commands to keep the line breaks. However, with  spaces it's more problematic, since HTML will merge all multiple spaces into one space. But you could try to replace `" "` (i.e. a space)  with `"&nbsp;"` (i.e. a non-breaking space HTML entity, which will also be accepted multiple times after each other.

Comment: ...although I am really still not sure what you actually want - your question and your comments are a bit contradicting each other...

Comment: It will Be Really Helpful if you can Post A line Of code to do it.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

Solved! I found that it happens not by PHP but by `mysqli_real_escape_string()` Function. So I found a way to solve my problem.

Comment: Ah....Isn't it a Mysql function? I thought it is because it need a Database Connection :)